# Question about the "pointed" property of proper cone

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm reading Boyd's Convex Optimization and have some question about the proper cone.
The following is the property of a proper cone:
•K is convex.
• K is closed.
• K is solid, which means it has nonempty interior.
• K is pointed, which means that it contains no line (or equivalently, x ∈ K, − x ∈ K =⇒ x = 0).
How can "x ∈ K, − x ∈ K =⇒ x = 0" be proved? Supposed the vertex of the cone is not located at original point, then some point in the cone will not satisfy this property.

Comment: I don't understand your thinking here. If the "vertex of the cone is not located at the original point", _then it's not a proper cone._  (In fact, it's not even a cone, most likely.)This is the _definition_ of a proper cone, and it must satisfy all four properties.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. The last property can be deduced from the definition of cone.  A set C is called a cone, or nonnegative homogeneous, if for every x ∈ C and θ ≥ 0 we have θx ∈ C.  I messed up the cone in convex optimization and the cone in geometry.